# How do I increase my Point Multiplier?

Tags: danmaku-unlimited-2

On Danmaku Unlimted 2, there is a point multiplier. As I play through a level, it increases, and when I take damage, it drops. But, I have no idea what causes it to increase. Is it based on enemy kills, or on how long you go without taking damage?

[image]

That is not me playing, just one of the first images I could fine that has decent quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Classic mode. You gain multiplier by killing enemies inside your outerfield (the circle surrounding you) and collecting the diamonds that drop.

In Burst Mode. you must use your burst attack to destroy bullets and then collect the bits. Those will be added to your multiplier.

[source on scoring](http://steamcommunity.com/app/280560/discussions/0/540737414876784972/?insideModal=1#c540737414906369257)

Comment: That makes sense, I was guessing it involved the diamonds that dropped, but I had no idea what caused them to appear.